# How do I set the server_default for a MySQL SET in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I've got a MySQL set column I'm describing using `sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.SET` and I want to set the `server_default` arg to a set containing two values. I'm looking for something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import SET
class MyTable(Model):
    letters = Column(SET('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), server_default=['a','b'])
```

If I try something as simple as the above I get:

`Argument 'arg' is expected to be one of type '<class 'str'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ClauseElement'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause'>', got '<class 'list'>'`

Is there somewhere I can find a list of ClauseElements I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best reference for different `ClauseElement`s is ["Column Elements and Expressions"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html).

From reading ["The SET Type"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) it seems that a common way to pass values to a SET column in MySQL is to use a (SQL) string literal with comma separated values. One way then would be to use SQLAlchemy's [`literal()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal), which produces a suitable bind parameter. You would then pass a literal string like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import literal
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import SET

class MyTable(Model):

    letters = Column(SET('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), server_default=literal('a,b'))
```